# How to determine class frequencies from (batched) tf.data.Dataset object

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to understand the frequencies of cat vs dog in my dataset to understand the balance of the dataset (which will then determine what classification metric to use and/or what class weights to assign). How can I do this please with a tf.data.Dataset object as generated below?

```
train_path  = '../input/cat-and-dog/training_set/training_set'
BATCH_SIZE  = 32
RANDOM_SEED = 42
IMG_HEIGHT  = 256
IMG_WIDTH   = 256

train_ds = keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    train_path,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    label_mode='binary',
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="training",
    seed=RANDOM_SEED,
    image_size=(IMG_HEIGHT,IMG_WIDTH)
)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how-to-get-samples-per-class-for-tensorflow-dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67895488/how-to-get-samples-per-class-for-tensorflow-dataset/67895702#67895702)

Comment: Thanks, but have solved it now.

Answer (score 2):

```
train_ds = keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    train_path,
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
    label_mode='binary',
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="training",
    seed=RANDOM_SEED,
    image_size=(IMG_HEIGHT,IMG_WIDTH)
)

class_names = train_ds.class_names

def class_distribution(dataset):
    class_values = []
    total_batches = dataset.__len__().numpy()
    for batch, element in enumerate(dataset.as_numpy_iterator()):
        if batch+1 == total_batches:
            for i in range(len(element[1])):
                class_values.append(class_names[int(element[1][i])])
        else:
            for i in range(BATCH_SIZE):
                class_values.append(class_names[int(element[1][i])])

    class_n, frequency = np.unique(np.array(class_values), return_counts=True)
    frequency = frequency/len(class_values)
    return pd.DataFrame(frequency, class_n, columns=["Percent"])

train_ds_class_dist = class_distribution(train_ds)

print(train_ds_class_dist)
```